# Strict OR in waterline where close

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

```
Partie.find({
    id: rez
}).where({or : [
    {enCours:false}, {mortSubite:false}]
  })
  .exec(function(e, r) {
       res.json(200, r);

  });
```

So my goal is to select all object containing enCours: false OR mortSubite:false. So I don't want to get object which have both values to false. This will return those, so how can I make a strict

Comment: I think this solution is absolutely clean. You could post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. Feel free to post if you have something cleaner

```
Partie.find({
id: rez
}).where({
or: [{                            
        enCours: false,
        mortSubite: true
    }, {
        enCours: true,
        mortSubite: false
    }]
})
```